# Cannot play video on iOS Device and Device Browser

Tags: ios, xcode, url, video, mpmoviewcontroller

I am developing an iOS application with the function stream video from server. I think the problem come from my video url It cannot load video to simulator or iOS device, but the url working fine when I access on browser PC.
Could anyone help me on this issue? Here is my code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.210:12345/WallPost/Download?filename=TheEmpressOfChinaOriginalSoundtrack1422348924923.mp4"];

     _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];

     _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.contentURL = videoURL;

     _moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 200.0);

     _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

     [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

     [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];

     [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];

     _moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

     [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: Open that URL in mobile Safari browser

Comment: Safari browser of PC is working fine, but Safari of mobile not working

Comment: Ask your system admin to give access to that server (192.168.1.210)

MAKE SURE

Comment: I can access to that server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822420/ios-how-to-use-mpmovieplayercontroller try this one if it works update me

Comment: @Spynet thanks you for your solution. I already try It was working fine with simple url, but the problem my url could not play on iPhone's Safari, also not working with UIWebView.

Comment: So still issue exist