# Getting frames though a stream and display on screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone, http, mjpeg

I have a requirement of streaming from server and displaying the streamed content on the screen...Streaming is working fine using NSStream, and NSInputStream and NSOutputStream.How can I display it on the screen?

Stream used looks like  @"http://191.168.143.41:1212/;

```
            if(stream == inputStream) {

            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;

            len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];

            if(len > 0) {
                NSMutableData* datas=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

                [datas appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];

                NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:datas encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                [self readIn:s];
                NSLog(@"ss%@",s);
                 [self loadMovie:s]; //method for movie player 
            }
```

I tried to display this is in a movieplayer as below..

```
-(void_loadMovie:(NSString*)moviePrefix
   {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mjpg", moviePrefix];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    if (url) {
        _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

       _moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, 600, 450);
       _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        _moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
        [dic setObject:__moviePlayer forKey:path];
    }

}
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.view addSubview: _moviePlayer.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_moviePlayer.view];
[self.view addSubview: _moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer play];  
}
```

Is  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mjpg", moviePrefix]; correct way??

This displays a black screen.What is wrong?
If this way is not correct,Is there any other way I can display those frames? 
Can anyone help me to solve this...

Comment: `NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:stringWithFormat:@".mjpeg", moviePrefix, @"movie"];` why are you using `stringWithFormat:` two times

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan Sorry that was a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

MJPEG are only JPEG sent one after the other.
I worked a few years ago on this.
On a version of iOS (iOS5?), it was easily read with a `UIWebView`, but an update of iOS broke all this. This broke all my current work.
Maybe a `UIWebView` could do the trick today again (fix).

Anyway, since it's just bunch of JPEG, you could just read the JPG (detect start/end of JPG file), create the JPG image and show it in a `UIImageView`.

A work around (not tested), but you should get the whole idea:

//Properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *data;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   IBOutlet UIImageView *streamImageView;
```

//Initialize somewhere

```
_data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

//In the stream delegate method:

```
//Start JPG: FFD8 — End JPG: FFD9
UInt8 startJPEGBytes[2];
startJPEGBytes[0] = 0xFF;
startJPEGBytes[1] = 0xD8;
NSData *startData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&startJPEGBytes length:2];

UInt8 endJPEGBytes[2];
endJPEGBytes[0] = 0xFF;
endJPEGBytes[0] = 0xD9;
NSData *endData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&endJPEGBytes length:2];

[_data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len]; 
NSRange startRange = [_data rangeOfData:startData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [_data length])];
if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) //We found the start of a JPEG
{
    NSRange endRange = [_data rangeOfData:endData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(startRange.location, [_data length]-startRange.location)];
    if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) //We found the end of a JPEG
    {
        NSRange imageRange = NSMakeRange(startRange.location, endRange.location+endRange.length-startRange.location);
        NSData *imageData = [_data subDataWithRange: imageRange];
        streamImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [_streamImageView setImage:streamImage];
        [_data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, imageRange.location+imageRange.length withBytes:NULL length:0]; //We remove the start till the end of JPEG frame. Start at 0, since there could be garbage at the start.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding `moviePrefix` to the string

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".mjpg", moviePrefix, @"movie"];
```

Change it to

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mjpg", moviePrefix, @"movie"];
```

Comment: Are not you getting any warning related to this ?

Comment: The `@"movie"` at the end still isn't being used. Maybe `@"%@%@.mjpg"`?

Comment: Also what is this `@"movie"`? What is it's purpose here? Sorry I am unable to understand.

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan Corrected the mistakes, @"movie" is not needed ,i saw that in an example .But the player still shows black screen

Comment: Did you try streaming URL on any browser ?

Comment: As I supposed the error pointed ou by @OmerWaqasKhan doesn't solve your issue. Even if it was an error since it doesn't solve your issue, don't validate its answer as the one correcting your issue.

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan ,Yes i tried the url ...its working in browser

Comment: Check a detailed answer in this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822420/ios-how-to-use-mpmovieplayercontroller by Zoltán Matók

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/horsson/mjpeg-iphone/tree/55251a85e2c2489014036ddf5a491783f9b1962d

Used this to get the stream and display.It works