# MPMoviePlayer video not displayed in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I have the basic MPMoviePlayer code

```
moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:local_url];
[moviePlayerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[[Util get_rootViewController] presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
[moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
[[Util get_rootViewController].view addSubview:moviePlayerViewController.view];
```

It's working fine in iPad with 7.0 version. But it has not displayed the video in iOS8 and it is getting audio only.

I tried the answers which have been suggested so far, but still no luck.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerViewController` != `MPMoviePlayerController`. Your code is an odd mixture of both. So step 1 is to decide which one you're trying to use.

Comment: little confusion - you have presented movie player controller then added it's view as subview to other view...!! So eiather add it's view as subview or present its controller. Dont do both

Comment: The issue was fixed. Actually the problem is my root controller.. So i have been added one view controller and added the movie player class.it's working fine right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/somefile.mp4"];
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
```

Make more clear with this link:"[iOS: How to use MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822420/ios-how-to-use-mpmovieplayercontroller)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works on iOS 8 (personally tested.)

```
   MPMoviePlayerViewController * moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:local_url];

      moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

      [moviePlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];

      [moviePlayer.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

      [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

Comment: recheck your url. might be the problem with your link

Answer (score 0):

> The issue was fixed. Actually the problem is my root controller.. 
>   So i have been added one more controller and added the movie player
>   class.it's working fine right now.